# Google Places API Search for Keyword and City

Tags: google-places-api

I would like to allow users to search for a keyword + city to return results for that keyword in a city.

For example "starbucks Seattle" should return all starbucks in Seattle.

However, it doesn't seem that keyword search includes cities - and so "starbucks seattle" just returns nothing.

I think the autocomplete api has such functionality, but the places api does not.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [Places API Textsearch](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests) endpoint:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=starbucks+seattle&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=cafe+New+York+food&sensor=false&key=... returns  "formatted_address" : "316 Victoria Avenue, Chatswood NSW, Australia"