# Google Places API search by city again

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to search all cafe and restaurants in New York. Of course, I can use Text Search, as it recommended here - [Google Places API Search for Keyword and City](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963891/google-places-api-search-for-keyword-and-city)

But if I do a request like 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=cafe+New+York+food&sensor=false&key=MY_KEY

First element, which I got, is

> "formatted_address" : "316 Victoria Avenue, Chatswood NSW, Australia",

really no way to filter data by city? This data exists in address, why no good way to filter by city, only via keywords?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `location` parameter to your query (requires also to specify the `radius`).

so your query would look like :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=cafe+New+York+food&sensor=false&location=40.67,-73.94&radius=100&key=YOUR_KEY

see the full documentation here :
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests

Comment: Not ideal, because in specified radius more cities can be located.